# ReactiveCocoa 4 set up enabled/disabled Action

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa-4

I'm using ReactiveCocoa4 to add some basic login functionality to my project. I have set up 'username' and 'password' MutableProperties in my viewModel and bound them to their associated textFields in the viewController. So far so good, but I'm stuck on setting up the Action to preform the network request. Essentially, I want the Action to take an Input tuple (username: String, password: String) and have an output of my custom user object 'SBUser'. I'm also doing some basic validation on the username and password inputs and tying that to the enabled state of the Action. My viewModel code is below.

```
final class AuthenticationVM {

let client: Client
let authenticationType: AuthenticationType
let username = MutableProperty<String>("")
let password = MutableProperty<String>("")
let loginAction: Action<(username: String, password: String), SBUser, Error>

init(client: Client, authenticationType: AuthenticationType) {
    self.client = client
    self.authenticationType = authenticationType

    let validation = combineLatest(username.producer, password.producer)
            .map({ (username, password) -> Bool in
                return username.characters.count > 2 && password.characters.count > 2 })
            .skipRepeats()

    loginAction = Action<(username: String, password: String), SBUser, Error>(enabledIf: validation) { (username: String, password: String) in
        return SignalProducer<SBUser, Error> { [unowned self] observer, _ in
            self.client.request(API.logInWithUsername(username, password: password)) { response in
                        switch response.result {
                        case .Success(let user):
                            observer.sendNext(user)
                        case .Failure(let error):
                            observer.sendFailed(error)
                        }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I'm getting an error, Contextual closure type '*->SignalProducer<*,_>' expects 1 argument but 2 were used in the closure body. Is it not possible to pass a tuple like this to the Input of an Action?

Answer (score 1):

```
loginAction = Action<(username: String, password: String), SBUser, Error>(enabledIf: MutableProperty(validation)) { (username: String, password: String) in
        return SignalProducer<SBUser, Error> { [unowned self] observer, _ in
            self.client.request(API.logInWithUsername(username, password: password)) { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .Success(let user):
                    observer.sendNext(user)
                case .Failure(let error):
                    observer.sendFailed(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

typecast validation to mutable property then it will work `enabledIf: MutableProperty(validation)`

Answer (score 0):

```
public init<P : PropertyType where P.Value == Bool>(enabledIf: P, _ execute: Input -> ReactiveCocoa.SignalProducer<Output, Error>)
```

`enabledIf` must be PropertyType.